# Angular2 with TypeScript: Declaration expected compiler error after @component

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

Im getting this kind of error despite of the fact i imported Component from angular2/core what should be its source is files are not downloaded through npm install or my node is needs to be upgrade

Here is my file

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

})
```

Comment: Decorators and classes are just function when translated to JavaScript (ES5). Decorator must have argument - a function - to be able to decorate it. In TypeScript this means that you must put something after a decorator. You can find more details in [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a class right after the component.

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

})
class MyClass {

}
```

`@Component` is just a decorator that contains metadata for the class. In other words it just defines stuff for your class in a more elegant way.

> The @Component function takes the configuration object and turns it into metadata that it attaches to the component class definition. Angular discovers this metadata at runtime and thus knows how to do "the right thing".

[Read more here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#metadata)

Comment: why is it necessary to do that

Comment: I provided an update with a link to the documentation that you need. Try recreating the [**quickstart**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) tutorial from the official angular 2 website so that it becomes more clear to you

Comment: also if i do that new error comes at class name that experimental support for decorator is featured that might change specify --experimentalDecorator to remove this warning, which is not warning whole red line under class name

Comment: Well you need to do some configuration in your .tsconfig file. You need to enable `experimentalDecorators` like this `"experimentalDecorators": true`. That's also in the quickstart.

Comment: If im including "experimentalDecorators": true im getting 99+ error saying duplicate identifier main, cache etc, i also tried other configuration like exclude : node module specified in tsconfig at quick start tutorial

Comment: You either didn't specified `files` or `exclude` which means you get conficts probably from your node_modules folder if you installed typescript via `npm`. It's hard to resolve that errors when I can't see your code or your folder structure.

Comment: there are two folders node_modules and typings and a main file app.ts and angularcomponent.ts and there .js file, simple structure, yes i installed typescript using npm

Comment: what is this logic of conflicts why there is conflict and duplication

Comment: all error gone when i removed node.d.ts from typings folder